# implementation of bucket in unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, bucket

I read somewhere that once a bucket holds more than 8 elements it will become a red&black tree instead of a linked list. I know that java uses this policy but i'm sure about c++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard doesn't mandate any particular implementation.

Only linked lists are used in the libstdc++ and Microsoft implementations (I didn't study other implementations, so here I'm considering only these two). Both of them use one long linked list (libstdc++ - singly-linked list, Microsoft - doubly-linked list) that holds all the buckets. This allows fast iteration through the whole container and makes `operator++` operation on iterator `O(1)`.

The bucket array in libstdc++ holds pointers to one element before the first bucket element (because it is a singly-linked list). In Microsoft implementation the bucket array holds pairs of iterators - to the first bucket element and to the one past the last one.

Schematic representation* for libstdc++:

[image: unordered_set in libstdc++]

Schematic representation* for Microsoft:

[image: unordered_set in Microsoft STL]

* Both diagrams correspond to `std::unordered_set<Key>`. For `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`, `key` should be replaced with `std::pair<Key, Value>`.

Comment: Are the `value` objects stored next to the `key` objects but not depicted in the graphics here?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, sorry. I made these diagrams for `std::unordered_set` some time ago. For `std::unordered_map`, keys are key-value pairs. I added a comment into the answer.