# How to prevent std::unordered_map from rehashing in general?

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map

Is threre a way to fix `std::unordered_maps` bucket count at construction time and not living in the danger of it rehashing?

My case is the following:

- I have an object that can't be copied or moved. Once it's emplaced, it has to stay exactly in that memory spot until destruction, as this memory is being used continuously by another task.
- I want to put this object into a container. The problem is that the key would be a string. Strings are slow for maps, so I wanted to opt for `std::unordered_map`.

I didn't find anything on this topic on the internet. If I use reserve() or rehash(), `std::unordered_map` will still automatically rehash if it so pleases. How can I lock it in place?

Comment: FWIW an `unordered_map` is a node based container so rehashing doesn't move or copy the element.  It just moves the node to the correct bucket.

Comment: @NathanOliver this basically means that the node will contain a reference to the element? I looked at this (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and saw that it mentions references+iterators staying the same under the condition that it doesn't rehash.

Comment: Just use [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) to set proper number of buckets. This will prevent rehashing. [In doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) you can find: `Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than max_load_factor()*bucket_count().`

Comment: And for non node-based containers, you might still introduce indirection with (smart) pointers.

Comment: @glades Yes.  The node holds a pointer to the element.

Comment: @MarekR yes but I don't know how many elements will be put into the unordered map. It's just to prevent a string to string comparison I would (presumably) have in an std::map in the first line.

Comment: out of curiosity... on your previous question someone already suggeseted to store `std::unique_ptr<T>` rather than `T`. Why is this not an option?

Comment: Here is a schematic for typical `std::unordered_set/map` implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435975

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number True, this is because I want to use containers in the std::pmr namespace. Unfortunately, there's no std::pmr::unique_ptr

Comment: You might be interested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23132307) for an allocator aware `allocate_unique` (found via [P0211](https://wg21.link/P0211).

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks. This might come in handy.